# Linearity of a derivation of 1-form

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

> A tensor derivation $D$ on a manifold M is a countable collection of $R$-linear functions $D=D^r_s:\mathscr{T}^r_s(M)\to \mathscr{T}^r_s(M)$ such that $D$ obeys a product rule:

> $$D(A\otimes B)=DA\otimes B+A\otimes DB$$

> and it commutes with contraction:

> $$D(CA)=CD(A)$$

> **Theorem** :Fix $V\in\mathscr{X}(M)$. Suppose there is an $\mathbb{R}$linear function $D_V:\mathscr{X}(M)\to\mathscr{X}(M)$ satisfying:

> $$D_V(fX)=(Vf)X+fD_vX$$

> for all $f\in C^{\infty}(M)$ and $X\in\mathscr{X}(M)$. Then $D_v$ extends to a unique tensor derivation such that it acts on functions by $Dvf=Vf$.

In the proof it is asked to show that $D_v\theta$ is a one form and $D_V$ is $\mathbb{R}-linear$ when acting on one form.

**My attempt**:
I am starting by proving $\mathscr{T}(M)$ linearity so that $D_v\theta$ is a 1-form.

From the derivation definition:
$(D\theta)(X)=D(\theta(X))-\theta(D(X))$

Then $D_v\theta(fX+gY)=V(\theta f(fX+gY))-\theta(D_v(fX+gy))$

$D_v$ is not linear so how can I use the definition $Dvf=Vf$ to prove linearity?

Question:

How do I prove the assertion?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$-linearity means that $D_v(a\,\vartheta+b\,\eta)=a\,D_v\vartheta+b\,D_v\eta$ for any two $1$-forms $\vartheta$ and $\eta$ and for any *constants* $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, i.e. you should look at $\mathcal{A}^1(M)$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. It should be easy to check this $\mathbb{R}$-linearity using the calculations you already have carried out.